# Tensorflow suppresses logging messages bug

Tags: python, tensorflow, logging

Tensorflow makes logging messages hide and not appear when I run the code.

I have tried the following stuff but couldn't find a way to make my code work.

```
import logging
logger = tf.get_logger()
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)


import os
import tensorflow as tf

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
```

So my code is the following

```
import logging
import tensorflow as tf

logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')
```

I expected to have the debug messages into my file example.log but nothing appeared inside example log.
When I import tensorflow, the messages don't appear and when I don't they do.

I need to use both tensorflow and logging because I use an existing code. Is there a way so logging suppresses Tensorflow?

Answer (score 5):

Two facts:

1. [`logging.basicConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) will do nothing if the root logger is already configured:

   > This function does nothing if the root logger already has handlers configured for it.
2. `tensorflow` has the `absl-py` dependency that will try to initialize logging when imported [by appending a `NullHandler` to the root handler](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-py/blob/9d73fdaa23a6b6726aa5731390f388c0c6250ee5/absl/logging/__init__.py#L1153):

   ```
   # The absl handler will always be attached to root, not the absl logger.
   if not logging.root.handlers:
     # Attach the absl handler at import time when there are no other handlers.
     # Otherwise it means users have explicitly configured logging, and the absl
     # handler will only be attached later in app.run(). For App Engine apps,
     # the absl handler is not used.
     logging.root.addHandler(_absl_handler)
   ```

   Not sure why the handler is attached to the root logger instead of the `absl` logger, though - might be a bug or a workaround for some other issue.

So the problem is that the `import tensorflow` call will call `import absl.logging` which causes an early logger configuration. The subsequent call (yours) to `logging.basicConfig` will hence do nothing. To fix that, you need to configure logging before importing `tensorflow`:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
import tensorflow as tf

logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')
```

Rule of thumb: always call your logging configuration as early as possible.

#### Writing logs in default format to file

If you just want to write the default logs to file, `abseil` logger can also do that:

```
from absl import logging as absl_logging

absl_logging.get_absl_handler().use_absl_log_file(
    program_name='mytool',
    log_dir='/var/logs/'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the method offered by @hoefling, you can also clear the `handlers` of the root logger just before your logging configurations:

```
logging.getLogger().handlers = []
# ...
logging.basicConfig(level=level, handlers=handlers)
```