# Python logger format broken: I0716 instead of INFO

Tags: python, tensorflow, logging

By some reason python logger format sometimes kinda broken. I'm not sure what's wrong, looks like encoding issue:

```sh
I0716 23:27:10.491452 4409853376 tpu_context.py:209] _TPUContext: eval_on_tpu True
W0716 23:27:10.491577 4409853376 tpu_context.py:211] eval_on_tpu ignored because use_tpu is False.
W0716 23:27:10.619174 4409853376 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From bert-ner.py:423: The name tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter is deprecated. Please use tf.io.TFRecordWriter instead.

W0716 23:27:10.621710 4409853376 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From bert-ner.py:428: The name tf.logging.info is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.logging.info instead.
```

Which should look like:

```sh
INFO ...
INFO ...
WARN ...
WARN ...
```

The script is executed like:

```py
subprocess.call('python3 bert-ner.py ...', shell=True)
```

How to fix this?

Comment: `I0716` is not an error, but an abbreviation for `info message on July 16th` and comes from the standard logging configuration in `tensorflow`. I guess your custom logging configuration (should you have one) is not applied, then [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57009619/2650249) may be of help.

Comment: Well I'm not setting custom config for tensorflow at all. Will try to add

Comment: Then the output is as expected. For a custom config, calling `logging.basicConfig()` with the desired settings should be enough setup. If you want to mimic the default output, I think this format string should be a good start: `[%(levelname) %(asctime)s %(filename)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s`, however, if you want the exact same format, you'll need a custom `date_fmt` and implement a formatter that will calculate the timestamp in microseconds as the [standard attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) don't offer it.

Comment: @hoefling, thanks for the explanation. Now I understand what's happening at least.

Comment: Glad I could help! I also noticed an error in the format string I posted in the comment above; it should be `[%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(filename)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s`

Comment: @hoefling
It would be awesome if you post the whole code snippet for tensorflow formatting as an answer. And then I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Python API

If you just want to customize `tensorflow`s logging format, replace the formatter in `absl` and `tensorflow` loggers:

```
import logging
from absl import logging as absl_logging
import tensorflow as tf


fmt = '[%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(filename)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s'
formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt)

absl_logging.get_absl_handler().setFormatter(formatter)
absl_logging.set_verbosity('debug')  # for example

for h in tf.get_logger().handlers:
    h.setFormatter(formatter)
tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(logging.DEBUG)  # for example


# test configuration
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # test custom logger if you have one - should also emit in the same format
    logging.getLogger(__name__).debug('tf imported')
    # this issues a DeprecationWarning in tensorflow>=1.13, emitting a warning log message
    s = tf.Session()
```

The script emits:

```
WARNING: Logging before flag parsing goes to stderr.
[DEBUG 2019-07-18 14:03:15,662 eggs.py:20] tf imported
[WARNING 2019-07-18 14:03:15,662 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From eggs.py:22: The name tf.Session is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.Session instead.

2019-07-18 14:03:15.671392: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2019-07-18 14:03:15.674517: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 1992000000 Hz
...
```

#### C++ API

The log records emitted from Python parts now have different unified output. However, as you can see in the above output, the logs emitted from C++ parts are unaffected by that. Unfortunately, the log format in C++ code is not configurable as of now (18-Jul-2019), see the [`LogMessage::GenerateLogMessage()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/0b3c5ea103e9b63d05830ae5c45c249ee7fa6787/tensorflow/core/platform/default/logging.cc#L96) impl:

```cpp
void LogMessage::GenerateLogMessage() {
  ...
  strftime(time_buffer, time_buffer_size, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
           localtime(&now_seconds));

  // TODO(jeff,sanjay): Replace this with something that logs through the env.
  fprintf(stderr, "%s.%06d: %c %s:%d] %s\n", time_buffer, micros_remainder,
          "IWEF"[severity_], fname_, line_, str().c_str());
}
```

This means that you can't do much besides turning off log emits from library's C++ parts:

```
import logging
import os
from absl import logging as absl_logging
import tensorflow as tf

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'

...
```

#### Records alignment

If you're like me and don't like the log lines not being properly aligned, apply a slight modification to `fmt` string:

```
fmt = '[%(levelname)8s %(asctime)s %(filename)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s'
```

Now the output will look more readable:

```
[   DEBUG 2019-07-18 14:31:20,097 eggs.py:36] tf imported
[ WARNING 2019-07-18 14:31:20,097 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From eggs.py:38: The name tf.Session is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.Session instead.
```

#### Use microseconds and thread ID

The default `abseil` handler appends microseconds to date and also includes the ID of the current thread. You can do that too - the thread ID is provided by `logging` module, while the microseconds have to be calculated first (I used a custom `Filter` for that). The example script from above, revisited:

```
import logging
import os
import time
from absl import logging as absl_logging
import tensorflow as tf

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'

fmt = '[%(levelname)8s %(asctime)s.%(microsecs)06d %(thread)d %(filename)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s'
date_fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt, date_fmt)


class FilterMicroseconds(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        local_time = time.localtime(record.created)
        record.microsecs = int(record.created % 1.0 * 1e6)
        return True

filter_microsecs = FilterMicroseconds()


absl_logging.get_absl_handler().setFormatter(formatter)
absl_logging.get_absl_handler().addFilter(filter_microsecs)
absl_logging.set_verbosity('debug')  # for example

for h in tf.get_logger().handlers:
    h.setFormatter(formatter)
    h.addFilter(filter_microsecs)
tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(logging.DEBUG)  # for example


# test configuration
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # test custom logger if you have one - should also emit in the same format
    logging.getLogger(__name__).debug('tf imported')
    # this issues a DeprecationWarning in tensorflow>=1.13, emitting a warning log message
    s = tf.Session()
```

Output:

```
WARNING: Logging before flag parsing goes to stderr.
[   DEBUG 2019-07-18 14:39:04.522035 140546459115328 eggs.py:36] tf imported
[ WARNING 2019-07-18 14:39:04.522186 140546459115328 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From eggs.py:38: The name tf.Session is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.Session instead.
```

Comment: Thanks! Awesome guide. The only message I can't hunt down:
`W0725 16:57:55.042182 4446524864 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From .../bert/optimization.py:84: The name tf.train.Optimizer is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.train.Optimizer instead.`

Comment: The deprecation wrapper should be covered by the code in the answer; the example output for a warning for `tf.Session` is included. Tested the above code with the `tf.train.Optimizer`, the output is modified. Check your code again - if not, maybe ask another question and drop a link in the comments here to ping me.